# Insert lines when yanking rectangle rather than inserting among following lines?

Tags: rectangle, yank

Having copied the 3x3 rectangular region containing `a`'s, how can I yank/paste that content at the desired point without slicing into the following text?  The following is the behavior for:

- `M-w` (kill-ring-save), `M-y` (kill-ring-save)
- (copy-rectangle-as-kill), `C-x r y` (yank-rectangle)

(all using `C-x SPC` (rectangle-mark-mode))

```
aaa
aaa
aaa

Insert
here ->aaa
Here isaaa some text after 
the yanaaak point.
```

I would like to figure out how to yank, so that this is the result.

```
Insert
here ->aaa
aaa
aaa
Here is some text after 
the yank point.
```

I'll admit that I've been yanking rectangles at the bottom of buffers and then doing a normal region kill for some time now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing `yank-handler` text property from just killed text should do the trick, since this will make `yank` use normal `insert` instead of `rectangle-mark-mode`'s own insert function.

```el
(defun kill-ring-save--strip (orig-fun &rest args)
  (let ((rtv (apply orig-fun args)))
    (if rectangle-mark-mode
        (let ((killed (car kill-ring)))
          (remove-text-properties 0 (length killed) '(yank-handler nil) killed)
          (setcar kill-ring killed)))
    rtv))

(advice-add 'kill-ring-save :around #'kill-ring-save--strip)
```

Comment: Perfect!  `yank-rectangle` still behaves as expected :-)

Comment: When I put this in .emacs and restart, upon the first M-w (kill-ring-save) I get the error "Symbol’s value as variable is void: rectangle-mark-mode". Also, although I can get the error to go away by entering and leaving rectangle-mark-mode, it seems that the new code removes the visual confirmation I am used to getting when I do M-w, which highlights the mark briefly so that I can see the extent of what I copied.

Comment: I am wondering if someone can post an answer which doesn't depend on C-x SPC (rectangle-mark-mode), for instance I would like a function that I can bind to a special key so that when I do C-x r M-w (copy-rectangle-as-kill), then I can use the new binding to paste the copied rectangle as normal text. Is this easy to write?

Comment: @Metamorphic have a look at my simple solution, maybe this helps?

Answer (score 4):

Another solution without advising functions and just adding another function to bind to any key:

```
(defun my-insert-rectangle-push-lines ()
  "Yank a rectangle as if it was an ordinary kill."
  (interactive "*")
  (when (and (use-region-p) (delete-selection-mode))
    (delete-region (region-beginning) (region-end)))
  (save-restriction
    (narrow-to-region (point) (mark))
    (yank-rectangle)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x r C-y") #'my-insert-rectangle-push-lines)
```

You can operate with rectangles and normal kill-ring as usual. Also you are able to yank a previously killed rectangle with `C-x r C-y`.

This works by narrowing the buffer to the current line (or region).
Then yanking the rectangle and extending the region in a similar way like yanking to the end of the buffer.
Afterwards widen the buffer back to normal.

Comment: This solves an annoyance I've lived with for years. Thanks @jue.